# Integrate $\int\frac{6x^4+4x^2+8x+4}{(1-2x)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $$\int\frac{6x^4+4x^2+8x+4}{(1-2x)^3}dx$$

I tried $2\cdot\int\frac{3x^4+2x^2+4x+2}{(1-2x)^3}dx\:\:$ now after partial fractions  i have:

$$\begin{align}
&\>\>\>\>\>\frac{3x^4+2x^2+4x+2}{(1-2x)^3}\\&=\frac{A}{(1-2x)}+\frac{B}{(1-2x)^2}+\frac{C}{(1-2x)^3}\\[1ex]
&=A(1-2x)^2(1-2x)^3+B(1-2x)(1-2x)^3+C(1-2x)(1-2x)^2\\[1ex]
&=(1-2x)^3\cdot[A(1-2x)^2+B(1-2x)+C]\\[1ex]
&=(1-2x)^3\cdot[A-4Ax+4Ax^2+B-2Bx+C]
\end{align}$$

Need a bit help to find out $A,B,C$ and evaluation of problem.

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Since the numerator and denominator have leading terms $6x^4,\,-8x^3$, you lso need an overall $-\tfrac34x$ term.

Comment: First use long division to reduce the degree of the numerator. Then, for the partial fractions, you're making it harder than it needs to be. If you had $\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18$, would you do $\frac{4\cdot8}{2\cdot4\cdot8}+\frac{2\cdot8}{2\cdot4\cdot8}+\frac{2\cdot4}{2\cdot4\cdot8}$, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Actually, by my prior logic, we also need a constant term to clear the denominator's $x^3$ term. I'll leave the OP to compute its value.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$-\frac{3 \left(2 x^4+4 x^3-9 x^2-5 x+1\right)}{4 (1-2 x)^2}-\frac{13}{8} \log (1-2 x)$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substitute  $t=1-2x$. Then $x=\frac{1-t}2$

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{6x^4+4x^2+8x+4}{(1-2x)^3}dx\\
 =& \int \frac{6(\frac{1-t}2)^4+ 4(\frac{1-t}2)^2+ 8(\frac{1-t}2)+4}{t^3}(-\frac{dt}2)\\
=& -\frac1{16} \int \frac{3t^4 -12t^3+26t^2-60t+75}{t^3}dt
\end{align}

Comment: Can't get it @Quanto, could you simplify a bit, need those few skipped steps if possible (sorry for not understanding)

Comment: @John - see the edit

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use partial fractions for a solution to something, then you first have to check the numerator and denominator's degrees (the degree of a polynomial is the highest power in it, eg the degree of $x^3+5x-4$ is $3$).

- If the degree of the numerator is $\ge$ the degree of the denominator, then before using partial fractions we must use long division or some other algebraic technique to transform the fraction we're dealing with into a fraction with the degree of the numerator that is less than the degree of the denominator, and a remainder term. For example,
  $$\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}=\frac{x^2-1+1}{x^2-1}=1+\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)}$$
  and now we're in a position to use partial fractions.
- If the degree of the denominator is $>$ than the degree of the numerator than we can immediately proceed with partial fractions.

Your integral fits into the first category, so you have a bit more work to do before you can use partial fractions.